# Notation of category theory

Tags: category-theory

> Let $F:I \to C$ be a functor, where $I$ is an index category and $C$ is a category. Show there is a natural bijection between $\operatorname{Mor}_C(T, \lim_{i \in I}F(i))$ and $\lim_{i \in I} \operatorname{Mor}_{C}(T,F(i))$.

What is the meaning of $\lim_{i \in I} \operatorname{Mor}_{C}(T,F(i))$ ? Does this notation imply limits on the category of morphisms of $C$ or category of sets?

Comment: Since the rule $i\leadsto \mathrm{Mor}_C(T,F(i))$ givees values which are *sets*, you can probably answer this yourself!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez What I think about is that since $Mor_C (T, \lim_{i \in I}F(i))$ is singleton because morphism is unique by existence of limit, and also $\lim_{i \in I} Mor_C (T,F(i))$ is singleton since if $\lim_{i \in I} Mor_C (T,F(i))$ have more than two elements, then we may find two morphisms between them. Hence there is natural bijection between two singleton. Do you think my argument is reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a limit computed in $Set$, precisely of the functor $Hom_{\mathscr{C}}(T,-) \circ F(-):I \to Set$.